# Filtering multiline pcregrep match with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have data in multiple text files that look like this:

```
1  DAEJ             X            -3120041.6620      -3120042.0476     -0.3856      0.0014               
                    Y             4084614.2137       4084614.6871      0.4734      0.0015               
                    Z             3764026.4954       3764026.7346      0.2392      0.0014               

                    HEIGHT            116.0088           116.6419      0.6332      0.0017      0.0017    8.0
                    LATITUDE     36 23 57.946407    36 23 57.940907   -0.1699      0.0013      0.0012   57.5      0.0012   62.9
                    LONGITUDE   127 22 28.131395   127 22 28.132160    0.0190      0.0012      0.0013    2.3      0.0013
```

and I want to run it through a filter so that the output will look like this:

```
DAEJ: 36 23 57.940907, 127 22 28.132160, 116.6419
```

I can do it easily enough with grepWin using named capture by searching for:

```
(?<site>\w\w\w\w+)<filler>\r\n\r\n<filler>(?<height>\-?\d+\.\d+)<filler>(?<heightRMS>\d+\.\d+)<filler>\r\n<filler>(?<lat>\-?\ *\d+\ +\d+\ +\d+\.\d+)<filler>(?<latRMS>\d+\.\d+)<filler>\r\n<filler>(?<lon>\-?\ *\d+\ +\d+\ +\d+\.\d+)<filler>(?<lonRMS>\d+\.\d+)<filler>
```

and repacing with (ignore the unreferenced groups, I'll use that in other implementations):

```
$+{site}: $+{lat}, $+{lon}, $+{height}
```

but of course, at the cost of doing it manually through a GUI.  I was wondering if there's a way to script it by piping pcregrep output to sed for text substitution?  I'm aware of the `pcregrep -M` option to match the multiline regex pattern above, and I've been successful until that point, but I'm stuck with the `sed` end of the problem.

Comment: I'm aware that I can use backreferences `\1` through `\9` instead of named capture, but I opted for the latter as a matter of preference.

Comment: After steve's excellent answer below, I realize I still need to capture possible minus signs in oddly formatted negative value cases such as `-  6 29 27.798898` in the LATITUDE/LONGITUDE data rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be using `awk` to handle your text file:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { printf "%s: ", $2 } $1 == "HEIGHT" { height = $3 } $1 == "LATITUDE" { printf "%s %s %s, ", $2, $3, $4 } $1 == "LONGITUDE" { printf "%s %s %s, %s\n", $5, $6, $7, height }' file.txt
```

Broken out on multiple lines for readability:

```
$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { 
    printf "%s: ", $2
}

$1 == "HEIGHT" {
    height = $3
}

$1 == "LATITUDE" {
    printf "%s %s %s, ", $2, $3, $4
}

$1 == "LONGITUDE" {
    printf "%s %s %s, %s\n", $5, $6, $7, height
}
```

Results:

```
DAEJ: 36 23 57.946407, 127 22 28.132160, 116.6419
```

---

**EDIT:**

Put the following code in a file called `script.awk`:

```
$3 == "X" {
    printf "%s: ", $2
}

$1 == "HEIGHT" {
    height = $3
}

$1 == "LATITUDE" {
    if ($2 == "-" && $6 == "-") { printf "-%s %s %s, ", $7, $8, $9 }
    else if ($2 == "-") { printf "%s %s %s, ", $6, $7, $8 }
    else if ($5 == "-") { printf "-%s %s %s, ", $6, $7, $8 }
    else { printf "%s %s %s, ", $5, $6, $7 }
}

$1 == "LONGITUDE" {
    if ($2 == "-" && $6 == "-") { printf "-%s %s %s, %s\n", $7, $8, $9, height }
    else if ($2 == "-") { printf "%s %s %s, %s\n", $6, $7, $8, height }
    else if ($5 == "-") { printf "-%s %s %s, %s\n", $6, $7, $8, height }
    else { printf "%s %s %s, %s\n", $5, $6, $7, height }
}
```

Run like this:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! This brought me a little bit closer to the solution, with the following modifications:  `awk '$3 == "X" {printf "%s: ", $2} $1 == "HEIGHT" { height = $3 } $1 == "LATITUDE" { printf "%s %s %s, ", $5, $6, $7 } $1 == "LONGITUDE" { printf "%s %s %s, %s\n", $5, $6, $7, height }' file.txt`  Now, I need to modify _that_ further to allow for negative DMS values of Lat/Lon, i.e., the `\-?\ *\d+\ +\d+\ +\d+\.\d+` part of the regex pattern, where the possible minus sign may or may not be separated from the first integer value with a space.

Comment: Could I do something like  `awk '$3 == "X" {printf "%s: ", $2} $1 == "HEIGHT" { height = $3 } $1 == "LATITUDE" { printf (($2 == "-") ? "%s%s %s %s, ", $6, $7, $8, $9 : "%s %s %s, ", $5, $6, $7) } $1 == "LONGITUDE" { printf (($2 == "-") ? "%s%s %s %s, %s\n, ", $6, $7, $8, $9, height : "%s %s %s, %s\n", $5, $6, $7, height) }'`  to test first for the existence of a minus sign?

Comment: @alfie, I'll show you an `if else` block, just give me a minute or so

Comment: Thanks. I tried something that works in (http://ideone.com/p7AkL) but I can't get it to work in my machine. I'm running it in cygwin. I'm still struggling with the awk/gawk syntax.

Comment: @alfie, See my edit. I think you _could_ simplify a line or two, but you end up sacrificing readability. What do you think?

Comment: @alfie, With your code, you don't test for negativity in the second group of three. Can't these values be negative? Also, can HEIGHT be negative?

Comment: Thank you.  That worked beautifully!  I no longer test the second group for negativity because it's guaranteed to have the same sign as the first group.  So for my data, I need to remove the conditional tests `$6 == "-"` , `$5 == "-"` and the solitary `$2 == "-"`.  The HEIGHT could be negative theoretically, since it's measured against mean sea level, but I haven't encountered that before.  At any rate, I think I've learned enough here to add the necessary conditional test for _that_ unlikely case.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^DAEJ/,/^\s*LONGITUDE/!d;/HEIGHT/{s/^\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*\(\S*\).*/\1/;h};/LATITUDE/{s/^\s*\(\S*\s*\)\{4\}\(\(\S*\s*\)\{2\}\S*\).*/\2/;H};/LONGITUDE/!d;s/^\s*\(\S*\s*\)\{4\}\(\(\S*\s*\)\{2\}\S*\).*/ \2/;H;g;y/\n/,/;s/\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/DAEJ: \2, \1/' file1 file2 filen
```